# Executing python threads in an order

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a `list` and `n` threads. I would like to use some IPC mechanism to append to this list in certain order, the order is that the first thread writes into the `list` first and then the second thread etc.
Only thing I came up with is to use n locks and unlock another thread's lock after previous finish its task, but I don't believe this is correct solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In what sense do you consider this solution to be "incorrect"?

Comment: Please experiment with some code snippet and see if it is not a correct solution. :)

Comment: You should try first....you should only believe what you see...
I know its hard at first to be unsure about a solution and and still try it...But it pays off well :)

Comment: Is [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) what you are thinking of?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Queue module to do it:

```
from Queue import *
from threading import Thread, Lock

# this function will process the items in the queue, in serial
def processor():
    if queue.empty() == True:
        print "the Queue is empty!"
        sys.exit(1)
    try:
        job = queue.get()
        print "I'm operating on job item: %s"%(job)
        queue.task_done()
    except:
        print "Failed to operate on job"

# set variables
queue = Queue()
threads = 4

''' a list of job items. you would want this to be more advanced,
like reading from a file or database'''
jobs = [ "job1", "job2", "job3" ]

# iterate over jobs and put each into the queue in sequence
for job in jobs:
     print "inserting job into the queue: %s" % (job)
     queue.put(job)

# start some threads, each one will process one job from the queue
for i in range(threads):
     th = Thread(target=processor)
     th.setDaemon(True)
     th.start()

# wait until all jobs are processed before quitting
queue.join()
```

More information about Queue module, there's a god example at end of page: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

**@EDIT**
You can use a `Queue` with **FIFO**(first-in, first-out) or **LIFO**(last-in, first-out ).

**FIFO** example:

```
import Queue

q = Queue.Queue()

for i in range(5):
    q.put(i)

while not q.empty():
    print q.get()

>>> 0
>>> 1
>>> 2
>>> 3
>>> 4
```

**LIFO**:

```
import Queue

q = Queue.LifoQueue()

for i in range(5):
    q.put(i)

while not q.empty():
    print q.get()

>>> 4
>>> 3
>>> 2
>>> 1
>>> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Posibble solution was to put the iterable in the dictionary with integer as string key, then put back the result to that key.
the make dict to list on result
    import concurrent.futures
    import collections

```
def x(y):
    import random
    if y == 100:
        import time
        time.sleep(2)
    return y * 1000000000

def run(ordered, func, list_):
    print(f'ordred: {ordered}')
    if ordered:
        list_ = collections.OrderedDict({i: list_[i] for i in range(len(list_))})
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as thd:
            res = {thd.submit(func, v): k for k, v in list_.items()}
            for fut in concurrent.futures.as_completed(res):
                list_[res[fut]] = fut.result()
            return [value for value in list_.values()]
    else:
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as thd:
            res = {thd.submit(func, v): v for v in list_}
            return [
                fut.result()
                for fut in concurrent.futures.as_completed(res)    
            ]


v = run(True, x, [60, 70, 80, 90, 91, 100,101,102])
print(v)
print(v == [60000000000, 70000000000, 80000000000, 90000000000, 91000000000, 100000000000, 101000000000, 102000000000])

v = run(False, x, [60, 70, 80, 90, 91, 100,101,102])
print(v)
print(v == [60000000000, 70000000000, 80000000000, 90000000000, 91000000000, 100000000000, 101000000000, 102000000000])
```

result:

```
ordred: True
[60000000000, 70000000000, 80000000000, 90000000000, 91000000000, 100000000000, 101000000000, 102000000000]
True
ordred: False
[90000000000, 60000000000, 70000000000, 80000000000, 91000000000, 101000000000, 102000000000, 100000000000]
False
```