# Execute threads in certain order

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

When we launch threads, is it known for SURE which thread will be executed first **or is it something not predictable** ?

I say this because **square is always called first and then cube**.

```
import threading


def print_cube(num):
    # function to print cube of given num

    print("Cube: {}".format(num * num * num))


def print_square(num):
    # function to print square of given num
    print("Square: {}".format(num * num))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # creating thread
    cuadrado = threading.Thread(target=print_square, args=(10,))
    cubo = threading.Thread(target=print_cube, args=(10,))

    # starting thread 1
    cuadrado.start()
    # starting thread 2
    cubo.start()

    print("Done!")
```

**I would like to understand the method Threading.start()**

**Does the order of calling Threading start() matter?**

But, if I sleep the yarns with the same time, then it is random order

```
import threading
import time


def print_cube(num):
    # function to print cube of given num

    time.sleep(3)
    print("Cube: {}".format(num * num * num))


def print_square(num):
    # function to print square of given num
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Square: {}".format(num * num))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # creating thread
    cuadrado = threading.Thread(target=print_square, args=(10,))
    cubo = threading.Thread(target=print_cube, args=(10,))

    # starting thread 1
    cuadrado.start()
    # starting thread 2
    cubo.start()


    # both threads completely executed
    print("Done!")
```

Comment: It's not predictable. If you need them to run in a particular order, you'll need to use some mechanism in your code to coordinate them.

Comment: Incidentally, you'll want to call `.join()` for each thread before assuming they're done. Conceivably, your program could exit before either thread runs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172904/executing-python-threads-in-an-order

Comment: Hi @Barmar, so in the first example was it mere coincidence that they are executed in the order they were called? I imagine that order came up because of the speed.

Comment: Hi @sj95126 great, depending on how I put the joins()s in that order will the threads end, right?

Comment: yes, it's just by accident. The functions you're running are extremely simple, so they'll probably run to completion before another thread gets scheduled.

Comment: @Daniel: How you order the joins won't change how the threads run; a join might block waiting for a thread to end, or it might return immediately because the thread is already done. You just want to make sure all threads have finished before ending the program.

Comment: Thank you very much @Barmar, this is worth gold "so they will probably run to completion before another thread is scheduled" (+1), I needed to CONFIRM IF IT WAS DUE TO THAT.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sj95126, I thought join() worked ALSO to guarantee thread execution order, +1 to you too.

Comment: One last question @Barmar, can sleeping threads with sleep() help me to do "real tests" that simulate "workload" on threads?

Comment: Yes, but it still can't guarantee order unless you make the sleep times very far apart.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Yes NOW I get it, order is a very DIFFERENT issue it has nothing to do with sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to understand the method `Threading.start()`

A Python `threading.Thread` object is not the same thing as a *thread.* A *thread* is an object in the operating system—separate from your code. I like to think of a *thread* as an agent who executes your `target` function.

The purpose of the Python `Thread` class is, to provide a platform-independent interface to the various different *thread* APIs of various different operating systems.  One peculiarity of *Python's* `Thread` is that it does not actually create the operating system *thread* until you call its `start()` method. That's what `start()` does: It creates the underlying OS thread.

---

> Does the order of calling Threading `start()` matter?

Depends what you mean. Your program definitely always starts the `cuadrado` thread before it starts the `cubo` thread, but the whole point of threads is to provide a means to achieve *concurrency* in your program; and what "concurrency" means is that the things happening in different threads are not required to happen in any definite order. By calling `print_cube()` and `print_square()` in different threads, you effectively are telling Python (and the OS) that *you don't care* which one prints first.

Maybe `print_square()` will always be called first on your computer. Maybe `print_cube()` will always be called first on somebody else's computer. Maybe it will be unpredictable which one goes first on a third computer.

Sounds a little chaotic, but the reason why we like concurrency is that it gives the OS and the Python system more freedom to get things done in the most *efficient* order. E.g., if one thread is waiting for some network packet to arrive, some other thread can be allowed to do some useful work. So long as the "useful work" doesn't need the packet that the other thread was waiting for, that's a Good Thing.

Comment: Hi @Solomon Slow "Your program definitely always starts the cuadrado thread before it starts the cubo thread". We can say then, that Thread.start simply "SCHEDULES" the start of a thread, that is, it does not actually start it at that moment. Rather, from that moment on, the operating system will be in charge of starting the thread as it sees fit and that is why we do not know WHICH ONE WILL BE EXECUTED FIRST, is that correct?

Comment: In other words @Solomon Slow, you want to tell me that "The "scheduling" of the thread is in the order AS CALLED but who is going to start running first IS THE UNPREDICTABLE, right?"

Comment: @Daniel, Yes. The temporal relationship between anything happening in one thread and anything in another thread is uncertain. That applies even to the very first instruction that either thread performs: If you `start()` two threads one immediately after the other, you can't be certain which of the two will be the first to begin executing its `target`. The exception to the uncertainty is when the threads perform operations that "synchronize" with each other. E.g., if thread A is holding a lock and thread B is waiting for the same lock, then you can be certain that thread B will not acquire...

Comment: ...the lock until _after_ thread A releases it.

Comment: "but the reason why we like concurrency is that it gives the OS and the Python system more freedom to get things done in the most efficient order" Great @Solomon Slow, so when we want threads to run in a certain order, are we "affecting-altering" the "nature" of concurrency because WE are telling it the order and not the OS as it sees fit (we are "taking control away")? Although I understand that sometimes it is necessary to want SOME ORDER..

Comment: "Maybe print_square() will always be called first on your computer. Maybe print_cube() will always be called first on somebody else's computer. Maybe it will be unpredictable which one goes first on a third computer". - This helped me to solve many doubts I had, it gave me a very broad vision.+1